# How to place GUI components in java in the center?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a mini form, that suppose to look like this:

[image: like this]

So far I got this:

[image: my form]

The problem is that I need to have this gap from the left, so that my form will be at the center, but I don't know how to achieve this.

My code:

```
public class Person extends ClubAbstractEntity
{
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected String surname;
    protected String tel;
    
    public Person(String id,String name,String surname,String tel)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.surname=surname;
        this.tel=tel;
        JLabel[] labels={new JLabel("Id", JLabel.RIGHT),new JLabel("Name", JLabel.RIGHT),new JLabel("Surname", JLabel.RIGHT),new JLabel("Tel", JLabel.RIGHT)};
        JTextField[] textFields=new JTextField[labels.length];
        JPanel container=new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(labels.length, 1));
        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(labels.length, 1));
        container.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        container.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        for(int i=0;i<labels.length;i++)
        {
            
            //container.add(labels[i]);
            
            textFields[i]=new JTextField(30);
            labels[i].setLabelFor(textFields[i]);
            labelPanel.add(labels[i]);
            
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            
            p.add(textFields[i]);
            fieldPanel.add(p);
            //container.add(textFields[i]);
        }
        
        setSize(450,220);
        addToCenter(container);
    }
```

It uses its parent (a class that extends `JFrame`) method called `addToCenter` which gets a GUI component and add it to the center.

```
protected void addToCenter(Component guiComponent)
{
    add(guiComponent,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: well written question with well written code! Good Job!

Comment: 1) `setSize(450,220);` is no better than a guess. Even if that guess is right on one machine (JRE, PLAF etc.) it will be wrong in others. Instead center the panel with a `GridBagLayout` as shown in the first answer, add an `EmptyBorder` to it for whitespace, then `pack()` the GUI to the exact size needed. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: the setSize(450,220) is a demand that i got, thats the reason why i set it that way.

Comment: *"the setSize(450,220) is a demand that i got"* Rubbish it is. The *example* GUI is 460x230. BTW - forgot to add last time.. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a wrapper panel that uses the `GridBagLayout` with the default `GridBagConstraints`.

```
//addToCenter(container);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
wrapper.add(container, new GridBagConstraints());
addToCenter(wrapper);
```

Now the "container" panel will be centered within the "wrapper" panel and the wrapper panel will fill all the available space in the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

The section on using the weightx/weighty constraints will explain why this works.

Edit:

Another option is to use a `Border` on parent panel. A Border allows you to reserve space or add highlights to a component. In this case you can use an `EmptyBorder`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.

The difference between the two solution is that a Border is a fixed size, which works fine if the frame is not resizable. The "wrapper" panel solution works good if the frame is resizable as the panel will continually be centered in the space available as the frame is resized.

Comment: is there a way to do this with just GridLayout and FlowLayout? or even BorderLayout?

Comment: @LiavC, Each layout manager has different rules. Flow layout allows you to center horizontally but not vertically (and you would still need to use it as a wrapper panel). You are already using BorderLayout and it doesn't work (which is why you asked the question), so why would you suggest it again?, As I stated at the top of my answer this is the easiest solution! It is two lines of code. What is your issue with this simple solution? Nesting of panels with different layout manager is how layout management is done. It simplifies the code making it easier to maintain and read.